# What is the "Error initializing filter 'drawtext' with args..." error in using of ffmpeg at c# process class?

Tags: c#, process, ffmpeg, drawtext

I used this below code for create a resolution of a video and write text on it.

```
    var proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    strin OrginalResolution="nhd";
    proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = ffmpegPath;
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-i \"" + fileIn +
                               "\" -f mp4 -s " + OrginalResolution + " -vf drawtext=fontfile=/OtherProjects/ConvertProj/ff‌​mpeg/OpenSans-Reg‌​ular.ttf:text=Parsa" \"" + fileOut.Split('.')[0] +
                               ".mp4";
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

    proc.Start();
    proc.WaitForExit();
    string sdsd = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
    proc.Close();
```

I faced with this problem(some string output of `StandardError` is in below):

```
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file\r\n[Parsed_drawtext_0       
@0000000002fd8c20] Cannot find a valid font for the family 
Sans\r\n[AVFilterGraph @ 0000000000511660] Error initializing 
filter'drawtext' with args 
'fontfile=/OtherProjects/ConvertProj/ffmpeg/OpenSans-
Regular.ttf:text=parsa'\r\nError opening 
filters!\r\n
```

In **cmd** the same argument value of process works fine.
I read that this issue related to how to using **quotation mark** at using 
of **text** property of **drawtext** in ffmpeg.but I can't find any 
solution for solving this issue.

Can anyone help me?

Can anyone help me still?Is this a bug?
I used any solutions for escape from `:` in my code,but can't solve this problem.
It can't find font.I delete other filters of drawtext to findout that any of filters don't mistake, but still error exists yet.

`expansion=none` property of drawtext doesn't influence on this case, for escape `:`.

Comment: use the absolute path of the font file

Comment: @aergistal I used this 
`-vf drawtext=fontfile=D\\:\\\\OtherProjects\\\\ConvertProj\\\\ffmpeg\\\\OpenSans-Regular.ttf:text=parsa:fontcolor=white:r=25:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.3:boxborderw=3:fontsize=85:x=85:y=(h-text_h-85)`
but still have the same issue

Comment: @aergistal It work on cmd,but not work in c# process argument and return   the error which I said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with set working directory address value to `proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory` at process.and full answer is in this link:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/13dc1101-f1d0-4655-b4af-3f211927d5be/what-is-the-error-initializing-filter-drawtext-with-args-error-in-using-of-ffmpeg-at-c-process?forum=netfxbcl